# Overwrite a modules JS files with theme

Tags: magento2, javascript, overrides

I've been looking over the Magento 2 Docs for using custom JS and have been trying to add a modified version of `'configurable':'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable'` to my theme directory so that I can treat the drop downs for product sizes differently than other drop downs.

I've created a requirejs.config.js file in the root of my theme directory with the following:

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            'configurable':'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable'
        }
    }
};
```

I've then copied vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js to my themes Magento_ConfigurableProduct/web/js directory and added a alert to the `_fillSelect` method. However it doesn't seem to be taking effect.

I've run a deploy and cache clear and the file does show up in the pub/static directory correctly, however I can;t work out why this file is not being used in place of the old one.